# Why some Web service created by .net methods invisible?

Tags: c#, web-services

My code is below:

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {
    }

    public class event_t
    {
        public string place;
        public int day;
        public event_t()
        { 
        }
    }


    [WebMethod]
    event_t getEvent(string sms)
    {
        event_t tmp = new event_t();
        tmp.place = sms;
        tmp.day = 1;
        return tmp;
    }
```

}

My question is: why the getEvent Web Method is invisible when I runs it? 
according to MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3003scdt(v=vs.71).aspx
it should work.

Comment: Because the method your asking about is marked `private` and everything else is `public`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your getEvent method needs to be public.

```
[WebMethod]
public event_t getEvent(string sms)
{
    event_t tmp = new event_t();
    tmp.place = sms;
    tmp.day = 1;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really a foolish question!

Answer (score 0):

Set the accessibility modifier to public

```
[WebMethod]
public event_t getEvent(string sms)
```

The default is the least accessibility possible which explains why you can't see it.